# Fancybox page anchors

Tags: javascript, php, fancybox

Is it possible to use page anchors (http://example.com/page.php#jump_to) in Fancybox and if so how?

I have tried like you normally do with a normal HTML page, where it works, but it doesn't work in Fancybox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an iframe to display the Fancybox content, then I suspect anchors will work.